# Running Maven Command From Java Program (From Eclipse) Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven

I want to run Maven command from Java in Mac but I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn": error=2, No such file or directory
```

My code looks like this:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mvn -version");
```

If I run the following command, it works fine. The only issue is related to Maven:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -ltr");
```

Comment: does mvn work in your command line?

Comment: yes its work when i directly run from command line

Answer (score 0):

check to see if you have <mvn_installation_location>/bin in your /etc/paths.